# Perl special variables for regex matches

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to use one of perl's special variable to make this snippet a bit less large and ugly:

```
    my $mysqlpass = "mysqlpass=verysecret";
    $mysqlpass = first { /mysqlpass=/ } @vars;
    $mysqlpass =~ s/mysqlpass=//;
```

I have looked this info up and tried several special variables ($',$1,$`, etc) to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `s///` will return true if it replaces something.

Therefore, it is possible to simply combine those two statements instead of having a redundant `m//`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(first);

chomp(my @vars = <DATA>);

my $mysqlpass = first { s/mysqlpass=// } @vars;

print "$mysqlpass\n";

__DATA__
mysqluser=notsosecret
mysqlpass=verysecret
mysqldb=notsecret
```

Outputs:

```
verysecret
```

#### One Caveat

Because `$_` is an alias to the original data structure, the substitution will effect the `@vars` value as well.

#### Alternative using split

To avoid that, I would inquire if the `@vars` contains nothing but key value pairs separated by equal signs.  If that's the case, then I would suggest simply translating that array into a hash instead.

This would enable much easier pulling of all keys:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my @vars = <DATA>);

my %vars = map {split '=', $_, 2} @vars;

print "$vars{mysqlpass}\n";

__DATA__
mysqluser=notsosecret
mysqlpass=verysecret
mysqldb=notsecret
```

Outputs:

```
verysecret
```

Comment: Neat, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: The second approach looks like the most pure perl of the given answers. Still, I will probably go with the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, regular expression it, if you really want to visit the path of obfuscation.
See following code:

```
my $string = "mysqlpass=verysecret";
if ($string =~ /^(\w+)\=(\w+)$/) {
    print $1; # This stores 'mysqlpass'
    print $2; # This stores 'verysecret'
}
```

My recommendation against this though, is that you want your code to be readable.

Comment: What I like about this is the fact that I can make a sub that works for all the values I have in that array (pulled from file)

Answer (score 0):

The one you're looking for is `$_`.

Comment: Well, I get "uninitialized variable" with everyone of those, including $_.
Maybe I should rephrase and ask how to shorten this snippet